# FIXED: NextJS doesn't allow plugin to set change HTML (prevent re-render?)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, embed, render

here's my situation:

- I'm building a website with NextJS (SSR)
- I need to load a script. The script should find a  and put some HTML (scripts and iframes) in there.

The problem:

- The script doesn't seem to be able to change the HTML!

**Code example:**

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

export default function IndexPage() {
  const [clientSide, setClientSide] = React.useState(false);

  useEffect(() => setClientSide(true), []);

  return (
    <div>
      The script doesn't work when you navigate to it.
      <div
        id="publitas-embed"
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: "" }}
        suppressHydrationWarning
      />
      <script
        data-cfasync="false"
        data-height="undefined"
        data-publication="https://folder.bigbazar.eu/folder-21-2021"
        data-publication-aspect-ratio="1"
        data-responsive="true"
        data-width="undefined"
        data-wrapperid="publitas-embed"
        publitas-embed=""
        src="https://view.publitas.com/embed.js"
        type="text/javascript"
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Fixed!**

The script was loading on 'page loaded', which doesn't happen in NextJS when you navigate. So fixed by dispatching that myself:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (scriptLoaded) {
      window.document.dispatchEvent(
        new Event('DOMContentLoaded', {
          bubbles: true,
          cancelable: true,
        })
      )
    }
  }, [scriptLoaded])
```

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead. Stackoverflow does support [inline live demos](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 0):

The script was loading on 'page loaded', which doesn't happen in NextJS when you navigate. So fixed by dispatching that myself:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (scriptLoaded) {
      window.document.dispatchEvent(
        new Event('DOMContentLoaded', {
          bubbles: true,
          cancelable: true,
        })
      )
    }
  }, [scriptLoaded])
```